# How to apply filter in excel vba for the date range which is not in proper date format

Tags: excel, date, filter, date-range, vba

I have data something like below. Here the date fields are not in proper date formats and also not in the correct sequence.

[image: Sample Data]

And when I apply the filter of below
Start Date as "Feb 13 2017"
End Date as "Mar 20 2017"
I should get all the data filtered in between these date range.

Result should looks like below

[image: Filtered Data]

Appreciate your help and support.

Comment: Best is to convert those test-dates to actual dates, either in place or in a helper column.